# UK Postcode look up by street, on a budget of £0.00

Tags: postal-code

I'm planning a site which will need to have the ability to search for an address using partial details, like street name.  Addresses are integral to the whole working of the app.

Does anyone have any suggestions how I can manage this, given how the Royal Mail is wholly owned by the UK government but the information is not public domain?

The idea will need to be scrapped if I can't get this information.

Thanks,
Paul

UPDATE:

I'm not interested in getting into a debate about whether I will make money or how anyone would know that.  My question is not about whether the data should be freely available to everyone, which I think it should be given we are tax payers, the government answers to us, and the government owns the private company that owns the mail service.

This question has definitely run its course, but thanks for all the comments... :)

Comment: There is a free DB of the 1st part of post codes only somewhere out there ... but sounds like thats not accurate enough for you.

Comment: Unfortunately it is the address data I need. Thanks.

Comment: 4 years on and this question is still hugely relevant, yet no shift by Royal Mail means holding everyone back on their great ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is PAF (the postoffice address finder) is pretty much the only real answer as postcodes change more than we like to talk about. Your company would have to face the cost of paying for it. Having done a lot of work with postcodes in the past, I am not aware of a system that lets you have this information free.. I believe even if you tried to reverse engineer it from data lists (eg electoral roll etc) you have to pay for a full DB.

Comment: This isn't for a company. It was for a useful service. If the only way to do it is to pay or the data, then that means littering the site with ads and hope they cover the costs of the postcode searches.

Comment: I'm giving this as the answer to the question, and ask a new, modified question which better suits what I'm asking...

Comment: No I know you can do limited online questions, but the full DB sadly isnt available in its entirety for free. I guess like so many companies, why give it away when you can make money from it

Answer (score 2):

The information **is** the public domain. I **can** lookup a postcode.

Royal Mail tells you why there is a [limit of 15 lookups](http://postcode.royalmail.com/gear/content/html/sharedPopup.jsp?mediaId=32000665&catId=400145).

I'd also add that more than 15 lookups means commercial gain or profit: so you should pay for this information. As per their [commercial products page](http://www2.royalmail.com/marketing-services/address-management-unit/address-data-products).

Edit:

Let's say the website using this data is free, non-profit, charity, whatever. So you get access to the PAF for free. My website hits your web site to get free access to the PAF.

Comment: i take it you gave the question the downvote? My idea is not commercial, nor will it make any money. You really can't see any situation where what is public domain in many countries might I add, could be useful for everyone?

Comment: "more than 15 lookups means commercial gain or profit" What utter rubbish. Look at anything http://www.mysociety.org/ do and tell me that's not for the public good.

Comment: @James: they pay their coders so have to hsve some income And not for profit isn't no profit...

Comment: @gbn Given I do not stand to make any money unless I use ads, how is my idea commercial or for profit?

Comment: @Paul: how do I or the Royal Mail know that?

Comment: Their parent body is an officially registered charity. Any "profit" made is invested back into their strictly monitored aims. Look, sorry if I'm being harsh :-) Ordinarily, I would be sympathetic to you arguments. However, this is government data and I'm a big fan of open public government for citizens good not profit. As a UK tax-payer, I've already paid for this data once (Where do you think most of it comes from? local councils), why should I pay for it again to a semi-private body with a state-granted monopoly the government wants to privatise more?

Comment: @James: I'm a fan of open gov too. Which is why I left the UK. is the PAF available for registered charities, for example?

Comment: @gdn :-) Yeah, its pretty depressing here at the moment. Don't know, but I personally think it should be available to everyone. Free to charities would be great, but setting up a charity is hard and a significant block for small projects.

Comment: @gbn "how do I or the Royal Mail know that?".  It's irrelevant. My comment was in reply to your comment: "more than 15 lookups means commercial gain or profit".  Why does it mean commercial gain or profit?

Comment: That's my spin on it. Personal use (as a taxpayer) would be a few now and then.

Comment: That doesn't actually answer the question.  15 or more uses a day has no bearing whatsoever on its use being commercial or for profit.

Comment: @Paul: tough. I think so. So does Royal Mail.

Comment: A taxpayer can use the data for free. Does a taxpayer need more than 15 searches? As a taxpayer, why should someone else profit from this data? It could be 10, could be 20. 15 is arbritrary but plenty for fair use. Yes, it has gone on longer that it should have but you feel you have a god given right to this data. Deal with it.

Comment: @gbn Which still doesn't answer why you think 15 or more searches per day denotes for profit. I am aware that the Royal Mail do not care.  _I_ don't even care. If the solution is paying for the data then I will have to find a different way of capturing information or do some cost analysis and see if ads can cover the data access cost. My post is not about that.  But since this thread has gone on longer than it ought to have, how about you have the last word and explain why you think over 15 searches per day must be for profit?  You must have a good reason... :)

Answer (score 0):

Was just searching for a news article I remembered and found this :-)

http://www.guardian.co.uk/technology/blog/2009/sep/16/wikileaks-postcode-file-free-data
The link to Wikileaks is broken but maybe you can find it still.

Comment: Yeah, just thought it was interesting. Sorry, as said I'm a open data fanatic when it comes to government data.